# new windows 08 server, can't download using browser

Tags: windows-server-2008, java

by default it seems you can't download anything using the browser on the server when terminal server'ing into the box.

I need to download the java sdk to install solr, and also need to install winrar since I can't even unzip a file I uploaded from my mapped drive.

What setting do I have to change?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default on Windows 2008 servers the [Internet Explorer Enhanced Security Configuration](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/815141) is enabled.  You can either disable it, or add the site you are having with to the trusted/intranet zone.